# I changed the password for the database user of my website, updated wp-config.php and wordpress asks to be reinstalled

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have lost my `wp-config.php` and could not retrive the information that was there. So, I took a `wp-config-sample.php` and put again all the informations, including a new passwaord for the database user. Now when I go the website I'm redirect to `http://website/wp-admin/install.php`.

The database is there, all the Wordpress files and others are there. How can I get my site online again?

Comment: Did the new user that you created for the database *DEFINITELY* have all priveledges when you created it?

Comment: Yes, it has all privilegies. I didn't create another user I kept the same, just changed it's password. And I don't receive the "Error establishing a database connection" that usually occurs when there is something wrong with the connection between user and database, what I receive is Wordpress asking to be reinstalled.

Comment: It feels like WP cannot see that it's already installed.

Comment: The problem is solved. Please, check @RaviShinde answer at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/253126/68644

Comment: Oh! Table prefix, good call! Glad it worked!